# Structured data: ArticleBody with or without html tags

Tags: seo, google, microdata, structured-data, json-ld

We are currently rescripting our theme. The current version uses microdata for structured data, but Google doesn't seem to handle microdata completely well, therefore we are switching to JSON-LD.

When we analyze our current microdata setup with Google's Structured data testing tool, no HTML tags are shown.
When we parse the content of our (WordPress) blogpost into JSON-LD it does contain HTML tags, which also show in the structured data testing tool.

Few hours of googling haven't given me a substantiated answer if we should strip the text from all HTML markup (or some?) or if we should keep it in our JSON-LD setup.

Hope anyone can give me a substantiated answer.

Answer (score 1):

`articleBody` should be text without any HTML.

See the documentation: [articleBody - Schema.org Property](https://schema.org/articleBody)

Comment: @RohitGupta I edited a bit to make it clearer, but it does provide a direct answer to the question and a link to documentation.